# Android andEngine pixelPerfectCollusion

Tags: android, andengine

I used andengine pixelperfect collides for game development.Some time its collution is perfect but some time is not.I used PixelPerfectSprite for Srpite.

Comment: -1 This is not a question. Your question should ask a question that is answerable.

Answer (score 1):

AndEngine doesn't support pixel perfect collision detection in terms of sprite transparency.